# Capitalize the first word in input -React js + typescript

Tags: reactjs

I don't know why my auto capitalize html thing doesn't work. I need help to resolve the issue.

```
type InputProp ={
autoCapitalize?: 'none' | 'sentences' | 'words' | 'characters';}
```

then I'm passing this prop to the <Input> , next I'm going to the input in the app e.g

```
<Input
                    inputType={'text'}
                    inputName={'forename'}
                    placeholder="Forename"
                    onChange={something something}
                    autoCapitalize ="sentences"
                  />
```

Everything is working except autoCapitalize .

Comment: What's the code in your onChange?

Comment: autoCapitalize  is work on only virtual keyboards such as on mobile devices and voice inputs. It is not working on physical keyboards. you have to write js code for this

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers. They were very helpful. Actually the answer was easier than expected. I just added  style={{textTransform:"capitalize"}} to my input and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

```
//  if you need to capitalize first and lowercase rest
const capitalizeFirstLowercaseRest = str => {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
};

export default function App() {
  //  if you only need to capitalize first letter
  const capitalizeFirst = str => {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  };

  const str = 'alice';

  console.log(capitalizeFirst(str)); //  "Alice"
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{capitalizeFirst(str)}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```